# работа с запросами базы данных

Tags: sql, случайные-числа

как написать запрос, чтобы при обновлении таблицы в каждой строке в столбце присваивалась рендомная запись с другой таблицы.

А не как у меня 1 значение для каждой строки.

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Ships SET (weapon,hull,engine) = (SELECT weapon, hull, engine FROM Weapons,Hulls,Engines ORDER BY RANDOM()  );")
```

| Ships | weapon | hull | engine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

нужно чтобы рендомное значение присваивалось каждой строке в столбце.

А не всему столбцу

Comment: Переписать в виде  update с join (точный синтаксис различается в разных БД, которую вы не указали). И join выполнять с выборкой, которая дает скажем id обновляемых строк целевой таблицы и те самые случайные значения для заполняемых колонок. В том виде как сейчас БД видит что подзапрос одинаково выглядит для любой целевой строки и поэтому выполняет его всего 1 раз

Comment: метод execute это  sqlite